# Save summary table data itself in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

How should save summary report data in jmeter without clicking on 'Save table data'.
[image]

Note: I want to attach generated summary report data in SMTP request.

Answer (score 0):

You may generate [Dashboard Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#generation), it's much better and available since JMeter 3.0. Run JMeter in NON GUI mode:

```
jmeter -n -t <path_to.jmx> -l <log.jtl> -e -o <dashboard_folder>
```

You can generate it by your self or [in the cloud](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/09/generating-jmeter-report-dashboard/)

Answer (score 0):

You can even save the report automatically in GUI mode as well. Just enter the path and file name with .jtl(eg: c:/result/test.jtl) extension just above the report.

[image: Summary report]

The result is generated in the provided location from where you can use for SMTP. The receiver of the JTL file can open the file in MS Excel with proper formats giving appropriate delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a CSV view of the [Aggregate Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) via [JMeter Plugins Command Line Tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeterpluginscmd-command-line)

1. Install [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/) using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)
2. Add [tearDown Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) to your Test Plan
3. Add [OS Process sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) and configure it to run the following command:

   ```
   JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --generate-csv test.csv --input-jtl results.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport
   ```
4. Add SMTP Sampler after the OS Process Sampler and configure it to use `test.csv` file as request body or attachment
5. You might need to add the next line to *user.properties* file:

   jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=true